# Unable to pass variable from payload to url in python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass a variable named ID in to a python api function which will use the ID to call another api function inside the actual api

but the id field remains `None` in postman

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
> https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/target/id/None/id?isidRequired=True

this is my code

```
@D.route('/Checkcontactinfo/', methods=['GET'])
def checkcontact():
id = request.args.get('id')
ivurl: str = f'{xxx}/id/{id}/id?'
payload: Dict[str, Union[bool, int]] = {'isIDRequired': True,
                                        'id':id}

response = get_iv_response(url=ivurl, payload=payload)
ID_contact_totalresult: int = response.get('totalResults')
return id_contact_totalresult
```

Comment: Have you checked if `id = request.args.get('id')`  actually returns an value other than none?

Comment: it returns the value given in the parameter in postman , but it is not passing to next line

Comment: Can you explain more?Because I tried this code it's working for me.

Comment: i am trying to write a api which will call another 3rd party api which will have id and is id required as parameter , how ever isidrequried is passing correctly but the id which is number comes as none "https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/target/id/None/id?isidRequired=True" in the none area the id which i am passing via postman parameter should come